# How to implement coulomb counter using Sigma Delta ADC for Battery Gauge?

Tags: adc, lipo

I am trying to understand working principle of the fuel gauge units of the LiPo batteries.

During my investigation I found that coulomb counting method has been used to calculate energy consumption from the battery.

As to my question, unlike voltage, current highly depends on the load value, especially load is a complex digital circuit, therefore I need to sample current sensing resistor (which is a serial resistor between battery ground and circuit ground) very fast and high linearity. For this reason I think Sigma Delta ADCs are proper solutions.

How can I use Sigma Delta ADC to implement coulomb counter?

Comment: What makes you want to design one if you don’t know how they work?  Which specs are you going to use for current gain error? Sample resolution (us)? Cost savings?

Comment: I want to reduce my design cost.  I do not want to use 3rd party chip to do so...

Comment: Then you have no specs and conflicting requirements. Define the specs better in terms of measurements and cost savings

Comment: generally you don't need a high sample rate or precise measurement to characterize a battery/BMS.